# Converting one character type to another

Tags: c++

I'm creating a function which changes a character to lower/upper case. However I'm using templates to allow any character type (`char/wchar/char16_t/char32_t`) to be used.

My problem is how do I convert `wchar_t/char16_t/char32_t` into char so it can be used checked and converted by `std::islower(...)` and `std::tolower(...)` and the equivalent uppercase function and then to change them back into their original char type.

```
template<typename CharT>
CharT* UpperCase(CharT* str) {
    CharT* out;

    //Conversion goes here

    for(Uint i = 0; i < std::char_traits<CharT>::length(str); i++)
        std::strcat(string, str[i]);

    //Conversion goes here

    return out;
}
```

Comment: How do you plan on handling characters that cannot be represented as a `char`?

Comment: Note: MFC: CStringA and CStringW are converting characters (ANSI, UTF16). Your attempt is way too naive (You may use 'libiconv')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::islower()` and `std::tolower()` operate on `char` data expressed in the current locale.  There are also `std::iswlower()` and `std::towlower()` functions available that operate on `wchar_t` data instead (do note that they do not support UTF-16 surrogates, though).

You would have to convert your input strings to either `wchar_t` or localized `char`, do your lowercase comparisons/conversions as needed, and then convert the result back to the original encoding when finished.

Keep in mind that:

- conversions to/from localized `char` are potentially lossy for non-ASCII characters, depending on the locale.
- conversions between `char`(UTF-7/8 only) <-> `wchar_t`(UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on platform) <-> `char16_t` (UTF-16) <-> `char32_t` (UTF-32) are lossless, as all UTFs represent the entire Unicode repertoire and are specifically designed for lossless conversions amongst themselves.

So, to minimize data loss, I would suggest using `std::iswlower()`/`std::towlower()`, and then create some extra templates to help you convert your strings from `CharT` <-> `wchar_t` using the appropriate conversions. You can use standard locale-independent `codecvt` classes for `char`(UTF-8 only)/`char16_t`/`char32_t` <-> `wchar_t` conversions.  For `char` <-> `wchar_t` conversions where the `char` data is localized instead, you can use `std::mbtowc()`/`std::mbrtowc()` or locale-dependent `codecvt` classes.  There are no standard functions/classes to handle UTF-7, you would have to implement that manually.

For example:

```
std::wstring toWString(const std::basic_string<char> &str)
{
    // if output is UTF-8, use std::codecvt_utf8 or std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 instead...
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char>> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(str);
}

std::basic_string<char> fromWString(const std::wstring &str)
{
    // if output is UTF-8, use std::codecvt_utf8 or std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 instead...
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char>> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(str);
}

std::wstring toWString(const std::basic_string<wchar_t> &str)
{
    return str;
}

std::basic_string<wchar_t> fromWString(const std::wstring &str)
{
    return str;
}

std::wstring toWString(const std::basic_string<char16_t> &str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<char16_t>> conv;
    const char16_t *ptr = str.c_str();
    return conv.from_bytes( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ptr), reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ptr + str.length()) );
}

std::basic_string<char16_t> fromWString(const std::wstring &str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<char16_t>> conv;
    std::string tmp = conv.to_bytes(str);
    return std::u16string( reinterpret_cast<const char16_t*>(tmp.c_str()), tmp.length() * sizeof(char16_t) );
}

std::wstring toWString(const std::basic_string<char32_t> &str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>> conv;
    const char32_t *ptr = str.c_str();
    return conv.from_bytes( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ptr), reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ptr + str.length()) );
}

std::basic_string<char32_t> fromWString(const std::wstring &str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>> conv;
    std::string tmp = conv.to_bytes(str);
    return std::u32string( reinterpret_cast<const char32_t*>(tmp.c_str()), tmp.length() * sizeof(char32_t) );
}

template<typename CharT>
std::basic_string<CharT> UpperCase(const std::basic_string<CharT> &str)
{
    std::wstring tmp = toWString(str);
    std::transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), tmp.begin(), std::towlower);
    return fromWString(tmp);
}
```